# Azure Front-Door - Redirection is not working in some browsers

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

**Background:**
I have an Azure Front Door setup with a custom domain name. In the DNS settings for this domain name, I have added CNAME records pointing to the Front Door URL. That is, there is one CNAME record for **www**.example.com and another one w/o the www (i.e. example.com). It was added correctly in Azure and everything was working fine.

**The Initial Problem**
For whatever reason, the CNAME record example.com (that is, no www in front) could not be added due to a conflict. When it was added emails were not being delivered correctly. Upon deleting this CNAME record, emails are working fine.

To overcome this, I added a redirection rule in Front Door. When users type "example.com", we are directing them to "www.example.com".

**The Current Problem**
This redirection is working fine in about 75% of the browsers. We are getting a lot of users complaining that typing "example.com" shows server not found. However, typing "www.example.com" is working fine.

Here is the redirection rule.
[image: Direction Rule in Azure Front Door]

Any idea why this is happening? I would be eternally grateful if someone can please shed some light. Thank you.